# Update Query PHP - wiping rather than updating

Tags: php

This is for an assignment, so the code is based on how the learning resources are presented. I have a plant database that I have to make changes to, and then update plantID no.2. I have created the form which is then populated with plantID 2 info, but when I click the Update button after making changes, it wipes all the info for that entry in the database. I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. Any help would be awesome.

```js
<?php

// MySQL Database Connect
require_once("connect.php");
 
// read the values from the form and store in variables
$botanicName = $_POST['bot_name'];

$commonName = $_POST['comm_name'];

$plantDescription = $_POST['pl_desc'];

$commonUse = $_POST['comm_use'];

$maxHeight = $_POST['m_height'];

$maxWidth = $_POST['m_width'];

$popular = $_POST['pop'];

 
// escape variables for security

$botanicName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $bot_name);

$commonName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $comm_name);

$plantDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $pl_desc);

$commonUse = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $comm_use);

$maxHeight = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $m_height);

$maxWidth = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $m_width);

$popular = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $pop);

 
// create the UPDATE query
$query="UPDATE plant SET botanicName='$botanicName', commonName='$commonName', plantDescription='$plantDescription', commonUse='$commonUse', maxHeight='$maxHeight', maxWidth='$maxWidth', popular='$popular' WHERE plantID='2'";
 
//execute the query

$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query );

// check for errors
if(!$results) {
    
echo ("Query error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    
exit;
    
}

else {
    
// Redirect the browser window back to the make_changes page if there are no errors
    
header("location: ../make_changes.html");
}
?>
```

```html
<h2>Edit a Plant</h2>
    
<?php

// run a select query to return the existing data for the record
$query = "SELECT * FROM plant WHERE plantID='2'"; 
    
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query );

// capture any errors    
if(!$results) { 
    
echo ("Query error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    
}
    
else {
    
// fetch and store the results for later use if no errors
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

$bot_name = $row['botanicName'];

$comm_name = $row['commonName'];

$pl_desc = $row['plantDescription'];

$comm_use = $row['commonUse'];

$m_height = $row['maxHeight'];

$m_width = $row['maxWidth'];

$pop = $row['popular'];
    
}
    
}
    
?>

<form method="post" action="code/update_plant.php">

<p>Botanic Name: <input type="text" name="botanicName" value="<?=$bot_name?>" required></p>

<p>Common Name: <input type="text" name="commonName" value="<?=$comm_name?>"required></p>

<p>Plant Description: <input type="text" name="plantDescription" value="<?=$pl_desc?>" required></p>

<p>Common Use: <input type="text" name="commonUse" value="<?=$m_height?>" required></p>

<p>Max. Height (m): <input type="text" name="maxHeight" value="<?=$m_height?>" required></p>

<p>Max. Width (m): <input type="text" name="maxWidth" value="<?=$m_width?>" required></p>

<p>Popular? (Y/N): <input type="text" name="popular" value="<?=$pop?>"required></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value= "Update">

</form>
```

Comment: Because, both your SELECT and UPDATE statements use the same record in the WHERE clause.

Comment: you have too many unclosed questions, IMHO. You commented under "one" answer.

Comment: Since this is an assignment then you should learn how to debug your code. In this instance the queries don't seem to be working. To debug just echo out the $query string and see what is happening.

Comment: Funk Forty Niner - Can you tell me how to close a question? My only comments for the answers I get would be - "Thank you, I will try this" - a comment which is frowned upon by this community. This is not the first time you have down-voted my questions and commented on my questions. This is trolling-behaviour. Again, I'm a early-stages student. Please skip over my questions if they are beneath you.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Seeing as we haven't covered this yet I will research answers to this topic here.

Comment: Can you post the table definition along with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters sent to `$_POST` have the `name` key in your input so your `$_POST['bot_name']` for example is empty, the correct way to get that name is `$_POST['botanicName']`.

This will be your post parameters:

```
$botanicName = $_POST['botanicName'];

$commonName = $_POST['commonName'];

$plantDescription = $_POST['plantDescription'];

$commonUse = $_POST['commonUse'];

$maxHeight = $_POST['maxHeight'];

$maxWidth = $_POST['maxWidth'];

$popular = $_POST['popular'];
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed these and it's still wiping the info.

Answer (score 0):

The names you use in the form have to exactly match the indexes you use in $_POST. You are using variables that are not defined.

```
// read the values from the form and store in variables
$botanicName = $_POST['botanicName'];

$commonName = $_POST['commonName'];

$plantDescription = $_POST['plantDescription'];

$commonUse = $_POST['commonUse'];

$maxHeight = $_POST['maxHeight'];

$maxWidth = $_POST['maxWidth'];

$popular = $_POST['popular'];
```

Fix the mysqli escape function calls:

```
// variable $bot_name does not exist therefore it results in a null value
$botanicName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $bot_name); // bad
// Fixed
$botanicName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $botanicName); // good
```

Make the form input names the same as $_POST

```
<form method="post" action="code/update_plant.php">

<p>Botanic Name: <input type="text" name="botanicName" value="<?=$botanicName?>" required></p>

<p>Common Name: <input type="text" name="commonName" value="<?=$botanicName?>"required></p>

<p>Plant Description: <input type="text" name="plantDescription" value="<?=$plantDescription?>" required></p>

<p>Common Use: <input type="text" name="commonUse" value="<?=$maxHeight?>" required></p>

<p>Max. Height (m): <input type="text" name="maxHeight" value="<?=$m_height?>" required></p>

<p>Max. Width (m): <input type="text" name="maxWidth" value="<?=$maxWidth?>" required></p>

<p>Popular? (Y/N): <input type="text" name="popular" value="<?=$popular?>"required></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value= "Update">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @ryantxr. I made the changes and it works now. I did initially change the indexes in the $_POST and didn't change them in the mysqli escape functions. Really appreciate the help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the indexes in the $_POST (I was using undefined variables) and change them also in the mysqli escape functions.